# Spark shell for Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

Notebooks are nice, but REPL is sometimes more useful. Am I somehow able to run spark-shell that executes on Databricks? Like:

```
spark-shell --master https://adb-5022.2.azuredatabricks.net/
```

I looked through available tools related to Databricks (databricks connect, dbx, ...), but it seems there's no such functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Databricks connect](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html) is the tool that you need if you want to execute code from you local machine in the Databricks cluster. Same as the `spark-shell`, the driver will be on your local machine, and executors are remove.  The `databricks-connect` package installs the modified distribution of the Apache Spark so you can use `spark-shell`, `pyspark`, `spark-submit`, etc. - just make sure that that directory is in the `PATH`.

P.S. but I really don't understand why notebooks doesn't work for you - `spark-shell` doesn't have any superior features compared to them.

Comment: I want a REPL. Databricks connect docs say about configuring client - part of that is running `databricks-connect test`, which does run some test using pyspark shell, but then instuctions jump to [setting up IDE](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#set-up-your-ide-or-notebook-server). Databricks-connect usage says: `usage: databricks-connect [-h] {configure,test,get-jar-dir,get-spark-home}`. There's not really an option to run REPL directly.

Comment: And for notebooks vs REPL - of course it's a matter of personal preferences and specific needs. I'm also using notebooks and there are obviously cases where notebooks shine. But just an example, a pattern I very frequently do in development/prototyping is: press up to bring up last command, slightly modify it, execute and see in the console window both results in chronological order. And there are a few more like this, enough to make me look for REPL.

Comment: I've updated answer - databricks-connect installs spark-shell, pyspark, etc., so you can use them

Comment: Now that's awesome, exactly what I was missing, thanks!